# WCF Services an error occurred while receiving the http response to(my domain), this could be due to the service endpoint not using the HTTP protocol?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I called a web method from IIS hosting, for the most of my requests web method responded me correctly, but unfortunately for some requests I gave an error occurred while receiving the http response to ... this could be due to the service endpoint not using the HTTP protocol.
This problem is related to the server which are processing our request, to find that we can call the method locally and trace all parts of the web method.

I spent six hours searching on the internet to find a solution, and then by tracing I found;

The data which the web method returned included emoji of like() in database sql server and Soap web Services was sensitive with this type of characters because Soap web services can not serialize them to make the response , I refined the data on database by removing the emoji and this error go away

The data on the database was like : abc

Comment: Is there still a question or did you figure it out? If there is something you think would help someone you can answer your own question, but first it should be edited to describe the problem in more detail. It doesn't clearly say what the exception or error is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.